# convert date format from mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a problem converting a date which is in string format.

I am using this code. But still not able to get the Date value.

In my code i need to save `FromDate` and `ToDate`  it's working fine but time also inserted. i want to insert date only not time

```
BD_Doctor iDoctor = new BD_Doctor();
iDoctor.DoctorID = iDoctorID;
iDoctor.ExperienceID = iDoctorExperienceId;
iDoctor.HospitalName = HospitalName.Trim();
iDoctor.Department = Department.Trim();
iDoctor.Designation = Designation.Trim();
iDoctor.FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate.Trim().ToString());
iDoctor.ToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate.Trim().ToString());
iDoctor.WorkDescription = WorkDescription.Trim();
iDoctor.SaveCreateInformation();
```

Comment: Javascript or C#? Why spamming tags? In which language do you want to do the convertion?

Comment: What does this question have to do with JS, jQuery or AJAX?

Comment: C# only sorry @MightyBadaboom

Comment: what about `FromDate.Trim().ToString("MM/dd/YYYY")` ?

Comment: @RahulHendawe represent text as a series of unicode characters show this error

Comment: @RahulHendawe, in posted code `FromDate` and `ToDate` have type `DateTime`, so it will be error

Answer (score 2):

You can save `Date` only:

```
iDoctor.FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate.Trim().ToString()).Date;
iDoctor.ToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate.Trim().ToString()).Date;
```

If you want to save date only in your database, your column type should be `date`

Comment: @VanustonIntelligence, Do you have some error or expected result is wrong? Could you provide actual and expected results please in your question?

Comment: 06-Jun-16 12:00:00 AM 08-Jan-17 12:00:00 AM See the output

Comment: time also inserted the record

Comment: @VanustonIntelligence, But `DateTime` always has time part, you can ignore this time part or you should create your own type which will have only needed properties.

Answer (score 0):

you can set format of Date like

```
DateTime TempFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate);
iDoctor.FromDate = TempFromDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

same as for todate

In database if you set DateTime datatype than date save with 2017-08-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: `FromDate` of `BD_Doctor` in question is `DateTime`, not `string` - you will get error.

Comment: if iDoctor.FromDate is Datetime than use 
DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: am using ajax function so i didn't call textbox from code behind page @SanketGandhi

Comment: using this 
DateTime.ParseExact(FromDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) @Vanuston Intelligence

Comment: i used this method but same issue